# WLLN about the Cardinality of a set generated by an i.i.d sequence

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Recently, I encountered an interesting problem with the cardinality of a set generated by a sequence of $i.$$i.$$d$ random variables.

Let $\{\xi_{i}\}$ be an $i.$$i.$$d$ sequence, taking values in positive integers. Assume $P(\{\xi_{1}=i\})=p_{i}$ and all $p_i>0$ with $\sum p_{i}=1$. We denote $D_{n}$ as the number of elements of the set $\{\xi_{1},\xi_{2}...\xi_{n} \}$. Then try to prove $\frac{D_{n}}{n}\to 0$ in probability.

My analysis is as follows.

We can write $D_{n}=1+1_{\xi_{2}\notin \{\xi_{1}\}}+...+1_{\xi_{n}\notin\{\xi_{1},\ \xi_{2}\ ,,,\ \xi_{n-1} \ \  \} }$

I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}(\frac{D_{n}}{n})$ and I can get $\mathbb{E}(D_{n})=\tbinom{n}{1}-\tbinom{n}{2}\sum p^{2}_{i}+\tbinom{n}{3}\sum p^{3}_{i}+...+(-1)^{n-1}\tbinom{n}{n}\sum p^{n}_{i}$. But then, I don't know how to prove $\mathbb{E}(\frac{D_{n}}{n}) \to 0$. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: You are using $i$ in two different senses and should distinguish them.  What is the probability all the $\xi_i \not= k$ for given $k$ across  $1\le i \le n$?  So what is the expectation of $D_n$?

Comment: OK - this is more complicated than I originally thought.  $\mathbb E[D_n]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\left( 1-p_k\right)^n\right)$.  For any $n$ and $\epsilon >0$, I think you can find a distribution of the $p_k$  with $\sum p_k=1$ which makes $\mathbb E\left[\frac{D_n}{n}\right]>1-\epsilon$ i.e. as close as you like to $1$, while I suspect that for any distribution of the $p_k$ with $\sum p_k=1$ and $\epsilon >0$ you can find an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ you get $\mathbb E\left[\frac{D_n}{n}\right]<\epsilon$ i.e. as close as you like to $0$.

Comment: This problem should be an infinite sum of p_i, for it takes values in all postive integers.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much.